# Scraping information from an external website using jquery load and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to scrape a random word from a random word generating website. Through reading other forum posts it seems that jquery `load` is the way to go in conjunction with some short PHP. I've created a PHP file called "grabber.php" which contains one line:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

Then I call this in my javascript like so:

```
$("#word").load('grabber.php?url=http://watchout4snakes.com/wo4snakes/Random/RandomWord #result')
```

The tag holding the random word on the external site is `result` and the tag which I want my site to hold the data is `word`.

For some reason it isn't working at all. It will delete whatever is held in the `word` tag header. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

If it helps, my html code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=timer.js></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2 id="time">The Timer is Here: </h2>
<h2 id="word">Word Goes Here</h2> </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can process the request purely through PHP, no need for the `$_GET['url']` either.

Within your grabber.php file, you can use cURL, or some library like Guzzle to make an HTTP request to watchout4snakes. When the request is received, you can use `json_decode` to turn the JSON string into an object. You can then send the word to the client using `$('#word').load()`.

Guzzle:
https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle